# How come frontier points exist?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Logically speaking, either a point is an interior point to a given set or it is an interior point to its complimentary set. Then how in earth does a third possibility arise?

PS: I'm not a topology student. Was just going through different concepts in topology when this question struck me. Simplified explanation would be appreciated. Thank you

Edit: I am mostly concerned with the set of real numbers in 1 dimension

Comment: So, given a circle, every point on the plane is inside it, or outside it, but cannot be on its circumference (logically speaking)?

Comment: What makes you think that every point must be an interior point of a given set or of its complement? The interior of the complement is not the complement of the interior!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich how do we define an interior of a set

Comment: Would it be logical to ask *Logically speaking, either a number is positive or it is negative. Then how in earth does a third possibility arise?* I don’t think so: you won’t find it ‘logical’ to make such an objection. So how comes you consider ‘logical’ to think there is only two possibilities in a question about topology? ;-)

Comment: If you're going through concepts in topology, somewhere in the material you're studying there should be a definition of "interior point."

Comment: How can you be attempting to do problems about interiors of sets before learning the definition of "interior"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think about the interval $I=]-\infty , 0[$.

Then $I$ is an open interval, hence each $x<0$ is an *interior point of $I$*.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}\setminus I =[0,+\infty[$ is a closed interval, whose interior is $]0,+\infty[$, therefore each $x>0$ is an *exterior point for $I$*.

And what about $0$?
$0$ is neither an interior point nor an exterior point for $I$, so we call it a *boundary* (or *frontier*) *point for $I$*.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a subset in a metric space $(X,d)$, we have three logical options for any $x \in X$:

1. $\exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq A$. Then $x$ is an interior point of $A$.
2. $\exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq A^\complement$. Then $x$ is an interior point of $A^\complement$, aka an *exterior point* of $A$.
3. If neither 1 nor 2 happens, whatever $r>0$ we choose, $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$ **and** $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A^\complement$ which means that for all $r>0$: $B(x,r)$ intersects **both** $A$ and $A^\complement$, and this exactly means that $x \in \partial A$, i.e. $x$ is a boundary (or frontier) point of $A$.

Typical boundary points are $0$ and $1$ for the set like $A=(0,1]$ in the reals.